# Rewrite URi with htaccess to related PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URi Like this:

```
http://my.domain.com/clientarea/verify/
```

and I want it rewrites to this one:

```
http://my.domain.com/verify.php
```

I mean when the first URi called, it shows the result of the verify.php at root path.

Anyone knows how I can do it?!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^clientarea/verify/$ /verify.php`

Comment: @Jon: TNX, but unfortunately it doesn't work!

Comment: Then you have to be more specific.  That rule will rewrite the exact URI that you specified to the exact php file you want, and goes in the `.htaccess` file on `/`

Comment: Yes, I've added that rule into .htaccess of root directory of subdomain... But result was not okay... It seems to have conflicts with other rules in this file... When I put the rule alone, it works fine... Anyway Thank you very Much.

Comment: @pro max then if you want to get around them, post the htaccess full code. If they are really big pastebin it.

Comment: @Jon: I put your rule above all of them and it gets okay. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this right after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^clientarea/verify/$ /verify.php
```